# SQL Using group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have 3 tables :

Role :

| id | name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | president | 1 |
| 2 | chief | 1 |
| 3 | caporal | 1 |
| 4 | president | 2 |
| 5 | caporal | 3 |

Group :

| id | name | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 1 |
| 2 | test2 | 3 |
| 3 | test3 | 1 |
| 4 | test1 | 2 |
| 5 | test3 | 2 |

User

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 |
| 2 | user2 |
| 3 | user3 |

I would like to select all group with a field condition : if userX have more than 0 role and if in these roles it has 'president' then return 1 otherwise 0.

So having data like this :

| user_id | username | role_condition | group_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | 1 | test1 |
| 1 | user1 | 1 | test3 |
| 2 | user2 | 1 | test1 |
| 2 | user2 | 1 | test3 |
| 3 | user3 | 0 | test2 |

I tried this :

```
SELECT u.id,
       u.username,
       if(LOCATE('president', group_concat(u.role)) > 0,1,0),
       g.name
FROM Group g
LEFT JOIN User u ON u.id = g.user_id
LEFT JOIN Role r ON r.user_id = u.id
```

Without a **group by** it gives me only 1 row because of the group_concat, and I can't use the **group by** because if I do that on user_id or username it will not give me all the rows I want.

I don't know how to do that and having the result I want.

Thank for your help :)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: The normalization looks a little weird. The group ids 1 and 4 are both "test1"  the name in the role table is massively redundant ....  And i do not really understand the desired outcome  :-(

Comment: @PhilCoulson 5.7

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig Yes i could use an other name, the customer wants to have a result I wrote, it's just the last collumn who change 'group_name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without aggregation, with EXISTS:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username,
       EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM Role r
         WHERE r.user_id = u.id AND r.name = 'president'
       ) role_condition, 
       g.name
FROM `User` u INNER JOIN `Group` g
ON g.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY u.id
```

If you want all the users, even those without any group, change to a `LEFT` join.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=82fcf9c2d9646c36a064238fcab363d5).
Results:

| id | username | role_condition | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | 1 | test1 |
| 1 | user1 | 1 | test3 |
| 2 | user2 | 1 | test1 |
| 2 | user2 | 1 | test3 |
| 3 | user3 | 0 | test2 |

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works well in local but on the customer server it gave me a 500, because in my request I had to to lot of exist (idk if it's the version of mysql 5.7)

Comment: @pham01 my query works for the requirement as you described it in your question and it provides your expected results. I can't say why you get a 500 error in the Mysql server.

Comment: Please look into the server error  log where you will find the exact error message resulting in the Error500 message. Post the error and the code where the error occurred and you may be helped

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig Yes it's a memory limit error

Comment: Please tell us the **complete error line**

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/domain/sites/xxx/www/vendor/symfony/error-handler/Error/OutOfMemoryError.php on line 1, referer: website.com